# What does the Qur'an say about the age of Prophet Nuh?

Tags: quran, prophet-nuh

On Wikipedia, it says:

> The influence of Noah's preaching and prophet-hood spanned 950 years according to Quran. -- [Noah in Islam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noah_in_Islam)

I've seen this claim before, but I don't recall it being in the Qur'an.  The reference it gives just says the exact same claim, without pinpointing where in the Qur'an.

I didn't find it in [Qur'an 71](https://quran.com/71) (Surah Nuh), and [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/105695) seems to contradict the precise claim on Wikipedia.

**Question**: What does the Qur'an say about the age of Prophet Nuh?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is mentioned in the Quran, in Surah Al-Ankabut ( Surah #29 ) verse #14:

> **وَلَقَدْ أَرْسَلْنَا نُوحًا إِلَىٰ قَوْمِهِ فَلَبِثَ فِيهِمْ أَلْفَ سَنَةٍ إِلَّا خَمْسِينَ عَامًا فَأَخَذَهُمُ الطُّوفَانُ وَهُمْ
>   ظَالِمُونَ**
>
> And We certainly sent Noah to his people, and he remained among them a
>   thousand years minus fifty years, and the flood seized them while they
>   were wrongdoers.

Prophet Noah (P.B.U.H) preached for 950 years but we don't know how long exactly he lived on Earth.